# List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName("Mumbai" , 5); returns zeo

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

This lines always returns zero even i have changed the places here i have atached my code !

```
 double lat= 0.0, lng= 0.0;

 Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.ENGLISH);    

 try 
 {
     List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName("Mumbai" , 5);
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+addresses.size() , 5000).show();
     if (addresses.size() >= 0) 
     {            
   GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
             (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
             (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

      Log.d("Latitude is:", ""+lat);
     Log.d("Longitude is:", ""+lng);

     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+lat , 5000).show();

     }
 }

 catch(Exception e)
 {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

both toast returns only zero. 
this is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationplacesautocomplete"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


    <permission
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationplacesautocomplete.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationplacesautocomplete.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>    
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCW_PkOeeRcL92tq5jPiSwewo6iaNwD43c" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

i have put all necessary codes even it is not giving correct answer

Comment: it returns `zero` because you have assigned `double lat= 0.0` and on the `Log` your are just showing it without any action

Comment: sorry now check and why List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(“Mumbai” , 5); this returns zero?

Comment: see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) how to use `List<Address> getFromLocationName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your variables "lat" and "lng", or get rid of them using your GeoPoint, like this:

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.ENGLISH);

try {
    List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName("Mumbai" , 5);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+addresses.size() , Toast.SHORT).show();
    if (addresses.size() >= 0) {
        GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
            (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

        Log.d("Latitude is:", ""+ p.getLatitude());
        Log.d("Longitude is:", ""+ p.getLongitude());

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+p.getLatitude(), Toast.SHORT).show();
     }
     ...
```